# Setting up new user allowed actions

Tags: permissions, users, user-management

I made a new user but have been trying to research how to limit their ability to make changes to the system.  I am basically looking for them to having the ability to change ifconfig settings.  Beyond that I do not want them playing around with the system.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Everything I look up online is about adding users and making them have root privileges.  Are there any in depth guides to user management and privileges.

Looking For:
Way to set a user to only be able to change ifconfig information. (Set IP address and so on)
In depth guides for user management and privileges/permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think of this the other way around: you don't take away privileges from users, you give them only those they need. So, just create a regular user, not an administrator. Then add this line to `/etc/sudoers` (do that by running `sudo vosudo`):

```
username ALL=PASSWD:/sbin/ifconfig
```

The user `username` will now have the right to run `ifconfig` but not anything else that a normal user wouldn't need to. They just need to run `sudo ifconfig` and it will work. However, attempting to run `sudo ls` or anything else with `sudo` will fail.

Comment: I never thought of it as giving always taking.  Excellent way to put it.  Just to confirm, I did a adduser username.  That is not an admin just a normal user correct?

Comment: @Keith yes, if you just used `adduser` that will be a regular user. You can easily check it by running `su username` to switch to that user's account and try running things. Do this before you give the user access to the new account.

Comment: BTW, if I want to require them to put in their password for actions would I change 'NOPASSWD' to 'PASSWD'?

Comment: @Keith yes, sorry, I changed that. I'd copied it directly from one of my own conf files.